# statically create a gridview of 2X2 imageviews in Android

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I'm trying to create a view that will include 4 imageView in a 2x2 formation. This is what I had in mind:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/pic1" 
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="4dip" />
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/pic2" 
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/pic3" 
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/pic4" 
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</GridLayout>
```

This doesn't seem to work, as when I run

```
setContentView(R.layout.grid_view)
```

I get this error:

```
Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class GridLayout
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I tryed to follow the instructions on http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html But it didn't help much

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your XML file on line 5

```
android:layout_height="match_parent""
```

The attribute value ends with `""` instead of `"`.

Comment: yes, just a small typo. This isnt what caused the error, of course. I fixed it

Comment: @Md.AbdulMunim I fixed the double "" that I was told about, not the error I asked about in this question :)

Answer (score 0):

You were supposed to use a grid view but instead you are using a GridLayout.
Try this blog post: 
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1518

By the way where is your `R.id.grid_view`? I don't see any name like grid_view in your xml.

Comment: grid_view is the name of the xml file. The blog post talks about using a grid dynamically, while I want it statically, like in  http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

Comment: You can not load a xml file like this. You can only load a specific component in your xml this way. Try this- `setContentView(R.layout.gridLayout1)` This should inflate the grid as your view inflater.